# Problem when loading php file into variable (Load result of php code instead of the code as a string)

Tags: php, master-pages, readfile

I have a site architechure where I assign content to variables and then print them in a master page. My problem is that php code in the sub pages is imported into the variables as strings. Is there anyway to make sure that the code is actually executed and the results is imported in the variables instead?

In the example below the php code in signup_header.php is imorted as a string to $page_header. The result is that "getVerifiedEmail(); ?>" is displayed in the form element instead of the e-mail address.

master.php

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <?php echo $page_header; ?>
</head>

<body id="home">
    <div class = "container">
       <?php echo $page_content; ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

signup.php:

```
<?php
    $page_content = file_get_contents("./include/signup_content.php");
    $page_header = file_get_contents("./include/signup_header.php");
    include('master.php');
?>
```

signup_header.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
   $('input[name="name"]').attr('value', "<?php echo $idpAssertion->getVerifiedEmail(); ?>");
    });        
</script>
```

signup_content.php

```
<section>
    <form class="task" method="POST">
        Name: <input type="text" name="name" maxlength="30" value=""/><br/>
        Email: <input type="text" name="email" value=""/><br/>
        UserId: <input id="userId" type="text" name="userId" value="" /><br/>
    </form>
</section>
```

Comment: Take a look at my suggestion below, its simple and I think it's what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
    $page_content = "./include/signup_content.php";
    $page_header = "./include/signup_header.php";
    include('master.php');
?>
```

and

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <?php include $page_header; ?>
</head>

<body id="home">
    <div class = "container">
       <?php include $page_content; ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

that's all

I hope that signup_content.php contains the similar template only

Answer (score 3):

Using [`file_get_contents`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/file_get_contents) will return the actual file's content. But you're looking to execute the file instead. You can use [`include`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/include) to execute a php file, however most often that file will create output itself already. This is probably not what you want.

Instead, you can still use `include` but catch the output into a buffer. This is called [*output-buffering* <sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/ob_start).

To make this more accessible for your program, you can create a small helper function that deals with the details. You can then just call that function that will include the file in question and return the actual output. You can then assign the return value to your variables.

**Example:**

```
<?php
    /**
     * include_get_contents
     *
     * include a file and return it's output
     *
     * @param string $path filename of include
     * @return string
     */
    function include_get_contents($path)
    {
        ob_start();
        include($path);
        return ob_get_clean();
    }

    $page_content = include_get_contents("./include/signup_content.php");
    $page_header = include_get_contents("./include/signup_header.php");
    include('master.php');
?>
```

Related: [Answer to *Modify an Existing PHP Function to Return a String*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8730878/367456)

Answer (score 2):

`file_get_contents` returns the actual contents of a file, what you need is [`include`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php), which actually parses a PHP file.

Comment: The problem is that the content of include is outputed instantly and not in the variable where I need it.

Answer (score 0):

in signup.php use

```
<?php
$page_content = include("./include/signup_content.php");
$page_header = include("./include/signup_header.php");
include('master.php');
?>
```

that is what you need.

Comment: The problem is that the content of include is outputed instantly and not in the variable where I need it.

Comment: @Mattias why do you need to hold it in a variable?

Answer (score -1):

use can use eval function

http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

```
$string = eval('?'.'>'.file_get_contents('signup_content.php',1).'<'.'?');
echo $string;
```