# php mailing using template

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Problem when loading php file into variable (Load result of php code instead of the code as a string)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7220830/problem-when-loading-php-file-into-variable-load-result-of-php-code-instead-of)

I am bit confused about following...

**message alert function**

```
public static function MsgAlert($email, $name, $subject, $message)
{
    $msg = include('mailer.php');

    $subject = 'New Message';

    if ($email != '' && validate_email($email))
    {
        $mailer = new PHPMailer();

        $mailer->SetFrom(ADMIN_EMAIL, SITE_NAME);
        $mailer->AddAddress($email);
        $mailer->Subject = $subject;
        $mailer->Body = Postman::nl2br($msg);
        $mailer->AltBody = $msg;
        $mailer->Send();
    }
}
```

I have put my newsletter design into mailer.php, and please check markup for that...

**mailer.php**

```
<div>
<h1><?php $subject; ?><span>27 September 2011 at 6:26 pm</span></h1>
<div>
<p>Hello <?php $name; ?>,</p>
<?php $message; ?>
</div> <!--message container -->
</div>
```

Am i using correct approach or should i do something more better as its not working. please suggest. thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot include to a variable, but what you can do is use php's [output buffering functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php) to achieve the desired outcome, e.g.:

```
ob_start();
include 'mailer.php';
$msg = ob_get_clean();
```

This will render the template and store the result in `$msg`.

Comment: and a +1 for you for actually linking to the OB docs.

Comment: thanks for correct and quick answer

Answer (score 5):

`include()` does not RETURN whatever you're including. It'll return true for success (file was included/executed) or false (file couldn't be included). With your current structure, you're need this:

```
ob_start();
include('mailer.php');
$msg = ob_get_clean();
```

to capture the output of the mailer.php script as it's included.

Comment: Well hello there, looks like your in my mind (or the other way round) :)

Comment: Yeah, saw the "another answer has been posted" just as I was clicking submit.

Comment: +1 Because your/our answer is awesome ;).