# PHP file_get_contents with a php file

Tags: php, file

I'm using [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) to merge a template and separate content and output them together as a page.

The problem I'm having is that if either of these files have a PHP statement,

```
<?php
    echo "example";
?>
```

The PHP isn't actually run, and the statement just seems to be part of the markup:

[image]

I thought at first that the PHP at the file I'm loading wouldn't be run first, but then I made a test page with the following:

```
<?php
    echo file_get_contents("http://stackoverflow.com");
?>
```

And [uploaded it here to see that it works fine](http://projectavian.com/stack.php) (processes the PHP first).

Should I be using a different function maybe?

Comment: your probably mean file function http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problem when loading php file into variable (Load result of php code instead of the code as a string)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7220830/problem-when-loading-php-file-into-variable-load-result-of-php-code-instead-of) - this is merely the same question, you might find some more useful tips in it's various answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to [include()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) the PHP file.

Be wary of the security concerns.

If you want to capture the file's output, use [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm more leaning towards an answer that explains why this function won't process the PHP in the file I'm loading first when it's local.

Comment: @MartyWallace, it's not meant to process it. `file_get_contents` reads the script as a plain text file and doesn't do any additional processing. You could do an `eval(file_get_contents())`, but that's just a backwards way of saying `include()`.

Comment: I see, but you can't append the result of `include()` to a string can you? There are a few things I do to the file I've loaded such as replacing some strings with `preg_match_all()`, etc.

Comment: @MartyWallace Use output buffering to capture the output from the included script, and then append the result to the string.