# fetch file with file_get_content and insert text into placeholder variables

Tags: php, html, file-get-contents

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Problem when loading php file into variable (Load result of php code instead of the code as a string)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7220830/problem-when-loading-php-file-into-variable-load-result-of-php-code-instead-of)

I am trying to create a template based application and I am having issues writing the user data into a pre-existing template file.

I would initially use `file_get_contents('template.php');`

and template.php would contain the following:

```
echo $user;
```

Is there anyway to insert data into a placeholder variable in a template file using `file_get_contents`?

I suppose I could use DomDocument or regex to insert the data into a placeholder string, but would this be possible to do with a php variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have control over `template.php` and are aware of the security considerations, you're probably looking for `include` or `require`:

```
include('template.php');
```

Will do what you want to do.

EDIT

Output buffering

```
ob_start();
include('template.php');
$result = ob_get_clean();
```

Comment: the thing is, I need to save the file after editing, so in that sense, includes or require doesn't really fit I think. Correct me if I am wrong though.

Comment: Ah, in that case I'd just wrap it with an output buffer